# Pandas Relative Time Pivot

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, pivot

I have the last eight months of my customers' data, however these months are not the same months, just the last months they happened to be with us. Monthly fees and penalties are stored in rows, but I want each of the last eight months to be a column.

What I have:

```
Customer Amount Penalties Month
123      500    200       1/7/2017
123      400    100       1/6/2017
   ...
213      300    150       1/4/2015
213      200    400       1/3/2015
```

What I want:

```
Customer Month-8-Amount Month-7-Amount ... Month-1-Amount Month-1-Penalties ...
123      500            400                450            300
213      900            250                300            200
...
```

What I've tried:

```
df = df.pivot(index=num, columns=[amount,penalties])
```

I got this error:

```
ValueError: all arrays must be same length
```

Is there some ideal way to do this?

Comment: @ScottBoston yes exactly, I want to disregard the actual month it happened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with `unstack` and `set_index`

```
# assuming all date is sort properly , then we do cumcount
df['Month']=df.groupby('Customer').cumcount()+1 

# slice the most recent 8 one 
df=df.loc[df.Month<=8,:]# slice the most recent 8 one 

# doing unstack to reshape your df 
s=df.set_index(['Customer','Month']).unstack().sort_index(level=1,axis=1)

# flatten multiple index to one 
s.columns=s.columns.map('{0[0]}-{0[1]}'.format) 
s.add_prefix("Month-")
Out[189]: 
          Month-Amount-1  Month-Penalties-1  Month-Amount-2  Month-Penalties-2
Customer                                                                      
123                  500                200             400                100
213                  300                150             200                400
```

Comment: This looks pretty cool, but I want the columns to be the eight months in order, regardless of what those months are. So the first one would be the amount in e.g. 7/2017 for one customer and 6/2014 for another. The second column would be the amounts for 6/2017 and 5/2014 for these customers respectively and so on.

Comment: @Memduh just see your comment under your question , check it now

Comment: @Wen - It is much better, :)

Comment: You can reverse your format terms and get the exact OP output request `.columns.map('{0[1]}_{0[0]}'.format)`

Comment: LOL... how do you like having all this back seat driving going on.  Kinda like pair programming.

Comment: @ScottBoston with your guys help, feel much better : -)